# What is the best / professional sentence to use between these two options

Tags: word-choice

Just a friendly reminder about the importance of utilizing the E Drive for documents relating to the Science Initiative and Doctors for Science.

or

Just a friendly reminder about the importance of using the E Drive for documents relating to the Science Initiative and Doctors for Science.

Comment: Never use a 5-dollar word when a 10-cent one will do (I really hope there isn't a special place in hell for pedantic hypocrites!). Use *use*. Forget *utilize* even exists.

Comment: I also think "using" is more forceful, and I presume the line wants people to always use the E Drive for those documents.

Answer (score 1):

"....using the E Drive".

Keep it short, keep it simple.